# properties.search.query is not a valid log or metric query

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure resource manager template that quite often, but now always, give me a strange error when I try to deploy it. My gut feeling is that this started a few days ago, but I’m not sure what the reason is. The deployments most of the times end with the error message:

```
"error": {
  "code": "properties.search.query is not a valid log or metric query.An error occurred while sending the request.",
  "message": {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "value": "properties.search.query is not a valid log or metric query.An error occurred while sending the request."
  },
  "innererror": {
    "stacktrace": "System.ArgumentException: properties.search.query is not a valid log or metric query.An error occurred while sending the request.\r\n   at Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.ResourceProvider.Validation.Ensure.IsTrue(Boolean value, String message)…
```

This doesn’t say me much :-( I have noticed that they deployment works fine if I remove this section from my template:

```
{
  "name": "[concat('ExceptionOccured ', variables('insightsNames')[copyIndex()])]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
  "location": "East US",
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('insightsNames')[copyIndex()]))]": "Resource"
  },
  "properties": {
    "description": "Some exception has been logged.",
    "enabled": "true",
    "source": {
      "query": "exceptions",
      "authorizedResources": [],
      "dataSourceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('insightsNames')[copyIndex()])]",
      "queryType": "ResultCount"
    },
    "schedule": {
      "frequencyInMinutes": 60,
      "timeWindowInMinutes": 60
    },
    "action": {
      "severity": "1",
      "status": "Active",
      "aznsAction": {
        "actionGroup": [
          "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', variables('alertGroupName'))]"
        ]
      },
      "trigger": {
        "thresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
        "threshold": 0,
        "consecutiveBreach": 1
      },
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction"
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('insightsNames')[copyIndex()])]",
    "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', variables('alertGroupName'))]"
  ],
  "copy": {
    "name": "insightscopy",
    "count": "[length(variables('insightsNames'))]"
  },
  "condition": "[greater(length(parameters('alertEmail')), 0)]"
},
```

This is a loop to setup alerts for some application insights projects. Is there some error in this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started getting this yesterday too. Same alerting structure, same error. I tried ~30mins later and it worked fine. Not what you wanted to hear, but I couldnt't find the reason why either.

Comment: It looks like you are right. It seems to work well as expected right now. I had problems with this for about two days. I leave this open a few days and will select your answer as accepted if the problems don’t come back.